# How do i style an OPTION field using INLINE text

Tags: css, select, inline

I am trying to style a `SELECT` / `OPTION` boxes using INLINE CSS.

The `background-color` does not seem to be working:

```
<option style='bakground-color:red'>text</option>
```

Basically, I want 3-4 options, but each line to have a separate colored background.

All the CSS examples I have found use external CSS files, or a separate STYLE section above the area I'm working on.

Is it possible to do this inline?

Comment: FURTHER: I cant do it with W3.CSS color templates, but i can do it with Regular named colors. HOWEVER. When i load the page, the colkor select box is white, but if i click on it I see all the options BELOW the top option, & they all have the appropriate color background. The 1st option is displayed twice. The top one is a clear background.. hard to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to give inline style then you can give.

The style is not working in your code because you have a spelling mistake.

You write `bakground-color` instead of `background:color`

```html
   <select>

  <option value="1" style="background-color:yellow">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" style="background-color:orange">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3" style="background-color:red">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4" style="background-color:green">Option 4</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="aa" style="background: black;">aa</option>
<option value="bb" style="background: blue;">bb</option>
```

This will show when you select an option from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it inline.

```html
<select>
  <option value="green" style="background: green;">green</option>
  <option value="cyan" style="background: cyan;">cyan</option>
  <option value="yellow" style="background: yellow;">yellow</option>
</select>
```